# C++ pointers and addresses

Tags: c++, function, pointers

i was just playing with pointers as function arguments and i know this.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void func(int *a)
{
  *a+=1;
  return;
}

int main()
{
  int a=1;
  cout<<a<<endl;//prints 1
  func(&a);
  cout<<a;//prints 2
  return 0;
}
```

My question is why does below code act similar to the one above, more precisely

when we call func(&a) from main function **in above case**

// starting address of that 4 bytes(size of int) of data gets passed and in our function(func) this address is stored in local pointer 'a' and when we write *(a) our compiler knows to read 4 bytes of data because its an integer pointer.

in short, my question is

**what exactly are we passing to 'func' 
when we call func(a) where 'a' is a variable which stores an integer value
and what exactly func(int &a) means**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void func(int &a)
{
  //cout<<*a;// error 
  a+=1;
  //  cout<<a<<endl;
}

int main()
{
  int a=1;
  cout<<a<<endl;// prints 1 
  func(a);
  cout<<a;// prints 2

  return 0;
}
```

sorry for bad english

Comment: Hint: google what is a `reference`. You're passing `a` by reference here.

Answer (score 0):

The two cases work similarly:

Case 1: `func` expects some pointer to some direction of an integer (`int *a`) which is, as you said, the first byte of a `sizeof (int)` bytes block according to the OS. When func is called you passed correctly that direction `func(&a)`, so the compiler considers that call as something like: `int p = &a; func(p);` anyway a pointer to that direction is actually what is being passed.

Case 2: func expects some direction of some integer (`int &a`). When func is called you just passed correctly the value `func(a)`, as all C++ compilers support reference paramenters, the compiler passes internally the direction of the passed value, `func (&a)`. Notice if you try to call func like `func (&a)` an error will occur because it would be passed something like `func (&&a)` while the compiler is just waiting for (`&a`).

OBS: We can also look to the second case `void func(int &a)` as a reference which is different from a pointer with an example:

```
int a = 10;
int &b = a;
cout<<a; //10 is printed
cout<<b; //10 is printed
b = 20;
cout<<a; //20 is printed
cout<<b; //20 is printed
```

Whether you modify a reference to `a` (i.e `b`) or you modify `a` directly, you are modifying the same value beacause they stand at the same direction of a.